# Could not upload image with Dio

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

I'm using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to upload images to backend. It often gives me the `Reference not set` response with a `500` error code. I tried uploading from another source and it  seems to be working. What's wrong with this code?

Haven't put the code for `performPostRequestWithToken()` because other methods are using it too and it seems to be working alright.

```
Future<UserModel> submitProfileImage(String imagePath) async {
 if (isEmpty(imagePath)) throw Exception("NULL image found");
 final formdata = FormData.fromMap({
   "profilePic": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
     imagePath,
     filename: "profilePic.png",
   ),
 });
 final usertoken = await getCurrentUserToken();
 print(usertoken);
 final response = await _dioHttpService.performPostRequestWithToken(
   "/User/UploadImage",
   formdata,
   usertoken,
 );
 if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
   return UserModel.fromMap(response.data["data"]);
 } else {
   throw Exception(response.statusMessage);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that the map key `profilePic` was causing the issues. This was definitely a problem from the backend because they were expecting the key to be `file`.
Changed that and it all worked out.